# Manipulating arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to add items of type data to an arraylist, which would display the name and age of 3 individuals in the form of ("Name", Age), I have the following code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Arraylist{
public static void main(String args[]){
    Data x = new Data("mark",41);
    x.Print();

    ArrayList<Data> arrl = new ArrayList<Data>();

        arrl.add("phil",21);
        arrl.add("sarah",43);
        arrl.add("william",37);

            for(int i=0;i<arrl.size();++i)
            {
                arrl.get(i).Print();
            }
```

I get an error on the words "add", saying that the method is not applicable for the argument. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show where in the [API documentation for `ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) there is an `add` method that takes a String and then an integer number as its arguments?

Comment: Erm, I wouldn't know. maybe am going about this all wrong. Hence am here asking for a bit of guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
arrl.add(new Data("phil",21));
arrl.add(new Data("sarah",43));
arrl.add(new Data("william",37));
```

Comment: Only this is the data is printed all on a single line as opposed to one one each line.